# Mounting a Django project with unix socket

Tags: django, unix-socket

Assuming I will use gunicorn to mount a django application:

1. How can I bind to both localhost:8000 AND to a unix socket?
2. How can I distinguish whether the request (in a view) is coming from the unix socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html) to listen on both a UNIX socket and a TCP port.

In order to distinguish between the two in your views, I'd simply run two processes - One that listens on the TCP port and one for the UNIX socket. When starting said process, specify an environment variable which you can later access in your view.

Comment: sounds good, and cleaner. I was planning to use gunicorn. how do I bind a unix socket with gunicorn?

Comment: See this link: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html?highlight=unix - basically just pass `unix:/path/to/socket` instead of the regular `host:port` syntax.